# Unable to connect to postgres service from other service running on the same docker swarm?

Tags: python, docker, flask-sqlalchemy, docker-swarm

I have this simple flask app:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import time

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']  = 'postgresql+psycopg2://{user}:{pwd}@{host}:{port}/{db}'.format(
    user = 'postgres',
    pwd = '123456',
    host = 'db',
    port = '5432',
    db = 'test'
)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % self.username

if __name__ == "__main__":
    db.create_all()
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80)
```

And I build it with the following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.6

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

As follows:

```
sudo docker build -t app .
```

And my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    image: app:latest
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    ports:
      - "4000:80"
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - webnet
  db:
    image: postgres
    expose:
      - 5432
    volumes:
      - /var/www/docker-tutorial/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 123456
      POSTGRES_DB: test
networks:
  webnet:
```

My `requirements.txt` file:

```
Flask
Flask-SQLAlchemy
psycopg2
```

And I am running with:

```
 docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml getstarted
```

Everything goes ok, but I got the following exception when connecting to the database:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not translate host name "db" to address: Name or service not known
```

Any Ideas what is causing the exception? Also I have tried to replace the host parameter for sqlalchemy to 'getstarted_db' which is the name of the service but that also did not work.

Comment: You have the `web` service in the `webnet` network, but db is not in the same network. try adding `networks: -webnet` to the db section just like you have it in `web` and see if that works/

Comment: yes this was the problem :), thank you. please can you add an answer and I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [maxm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1333724/maxm) comment I was able to solve the problem, the issue is that the `web` and `db` services are not in the same network. So my `docker-compose.yml` become as follow:

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    image: hello:latest
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    ports:
      - "4000:80"
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - webnet
  db:
    image: postgres
    expose:
      - 5432
    volumes:
      - /var/www/docker-tutorial/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 123456
      POSTGRES_DB: test
    networks:
      - webnet

networks:
  webnet:
```